# Firebase Storage: Programatically delete files from /tmp/

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I botched a Firebase cloud function and accidentally created 1.9 million images stored in `gs://myapp.appspot.com//tmp/`. That double slash is accurate--the server was writing to `/tmp/`, which I guess results in the path mentioned above.

I'm now wanting to delete those files (they're all nonsense). I tried using the Python wrapper like so:

```sh
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="../secrets/service-account.json"
```

Then:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('tmp')
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(bucket='tmp', prefix='')
for blob in blobs:
  print(' * deleting', blob)
  blob.delete()
```

But this throws:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/tmp?projection=noAcl: firebase-adminsdk-yr6f8@myapp.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to tmp.
```

Does anyone know how to allow the admin credentials to delete from `/tmp/`? Any pointers would be hugely helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this problem with gsutil command:

```
gsutil cp ~/<example-file> gs://<my-project-name>.appspot.com//tmp/
```

First of all, in my  [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) I am able to do it with one tick (whole folder) not sure if you consider this.

Anyway if you want to have it done with API I have found following solution.

1. I think (comparing to my test) bucket name should be: `myapp.appspot.com`
2. If you print the blobs in python you will get something like this: `<Blob: <my-project-name>.appspot.com, /tmp/<example-file>, 1584700014023619`>

The 2nd value is name property of blob object. I noticed that in this situation its blobs name starts with `/tmp/`

Code that works on my side is:

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('myapp.appspot.com')
blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
for blob in blobs:
        if blob.name.startswith('/tmp/'):
                print(' * deleting', blob)
                blob.delete()
```

I don't think its very elegant solution, but for the one time fix maybe be good enough.

I hope it will help!

Comment: Thanks a million! There are evidently several python clients to the firebase api, so my googling around was pulling down code / examples from each. This is super helpful!